# Add trailing slashs issues

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a google analytics filter which is designed to force a trailing slash on the end of URLs so we don't get duplicate pages of **mypage** and **mypage/** (courtesy of this https://www.getelevar.com/how-to/fix-duplicate-url-google-analytics/)

It's based on the following regex

`^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]*[^/])$`

It works most of the time except for in some of our URLs which contain years e.g **blog/2021/mypage** where the filter stops working. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this can make it work?

Comment: Maybe you just want `^(/.*[^/])$`?

Answer (score 1):

"blog/2021/mypage" is not matching because it does not have a leading slash.
try "^(/?[a-z0–9/_-]*[^/])$":

```
Mac_3.2.57$echo blog/2021/mypage| egrep '^(/[a-z0–9/_-]*[^/])$'
Mac_3.2.57$echo blog/2021/mypage| egrep '^(/*[a-z0-9/_-]*[^/])$'
blog/2021/mypage
Mac_3.2.57$echo blog/2021/mypage| egrep '^(/{0,1}[a-z0-9/_-]*[^/])$'
blog/2021/mypage
Mac_3.2.57$echo blog/2021/mypage| egrep '^(/?[a-z0-9/_-]*[^/])$'
blog/2021/mypage
Mac_3.2.57$
```